# PostgreSQL Subquery join and one value

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, correlated-subquery

Im not PostgreDev, got problem with returning just one value in subquery.

```
select * from
(
select m_id from TableA where m_id = 236779

)Main
inner  join
(
select m_m_id as l_m_id,date_created as l_date_created
from TableB
where
proc_type <> '-'
order by date_created desc limit 1
) CheckLastCode on (Main.m_id = CheckLastCode.l_m_id)
```

Will return empty set.

When I take down limit 1

```
select * from
(
select m_id from TableA where m_id = 236779

)Main
inner  join
(
select m_m_id as l_m_id,date_created as l_date_created
from TableB
where
proc_type <> '-'
order by date_created desc
) CheckLastCode on (Main.m_id = CheckLastCode.l_m_id)
```

Will return all from TableB.

Im trying to have just last value from tableB

@EDIT
It should work for every m_id in tableA

So my output:
M_ID | MAX(DATE_CREATED) for that M_ID| ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dd91f/2/0) that demonstrates the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA AS a
  JOIN TableB as b 
  ON a.m_id = b.m_m_id AND b.date_created = 
  (
    SELECT MAX(bs.date_created) 
    FROM TableB bs
    WHERE bs.m_m_id = a.m_id
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

If your tables have a lot of records you may want to apply a range in a WHERE clause to speed up the query, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA AS a
  JOIN TableB as b 
  ON a.m_id = b.m_m_id AND b.date_created = 
  (
    SELECT MAX(bs.date_created) 
    FROM TableB bs
    WHERE bs.m_m_id = a.m_id
    LIMIT 1
  )
WHERE a.m_id BETWEEN 2 AND 3
```

Comment: Well I added just one ID for testing purposes.
It should work for every M_ID.

ID | MAX(DATE) for that ID| ... for that ID

Comment: It will work only for M_ID = 236779.
I need to make it working for each m_id in table

select * from
(
select m_id from TableA --return 8kk m_id's

)Main
inner  join
(
select m_m_id as l_m_id,date_created as l_date_created
from TableB
where
proc_type <> '-'
order by date_created desc limit 1
) CheckLastCode on (Main.m_id = CheckLastCode.l_m_id)

Comment: *@VoonArt*, I just updated my answer to apply to your recently updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the second query to:

```
select m_m_id as l_m_id,date_created as l_date_created
  from TableB
 where proc_type <> '-'
   and date_created = (select max(date_created) 
                        from TableB 
                        where m_m_id = 236779 limit 1)
```

Comment: If you are getting the `max(date_created)` from a sub query, you also have to specify the WHERE clause of `m_m_id = 236779`, otherwise you may retrieve an unrelated `date_created` value.

Comment: *@Jorge Campos*, actually it appears that `l_m_id` is the alias.  The actual name of the field is `m_m_id`.

Comment: Yeaaah, you are right, my mistake. again. =/ I will correct again. Thanks.